# Is there a symbol for an "element"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there a math symbol that represents an arbitrary element?

This shouldn't be confused with the "element of" symbol $\in$.

Comment: You can only speak of an element in the context of a set where it belongs to. Then you can start with something like: let $x$ be an element of...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most non-toy situations one deals with more than one set at a time, so if there WERE such a symbol, it would get confusing.  A common convention is to use the lower-case version of whatever letter used for the set.  For example, $s\in S$ or $x\in X$.

Answer (score 2):

If we choose to look at *properties* instead of *sets* - on the grounds that, in many cases, we can conflate the two - then there is such a symbol due to Hilbert, although it's not popular outside of proof theory. However, I find it useful, at least in my own notes, and wish it had stuck around (although I wish it were denoted differently).

The symbol is this: if $P$ is a property, then $\epsilon x P$ is a term, and the axiom governing $\epsilon P$ is $$\exists x(P(x))\implies P(\epsilon xP)$$ - that is, if there is *some* thing satisfying $P$, then $\epsilon xP$ is such a thing. I think the choice of "$\epsilon$" as the symbol, here, is unfortunate since it can be conflated with the *relation* "$\in$," especially when reading older texts; Bourbaki essentially [used $\tau$ instead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_calculus#Bourbaki_notation), which I prefer notation-wise, but they also [used a logical framework I find ridiculous](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/inefff.pdf) (and the usage of $\tau$ is much more complicated than the usage of $\epsilon$); in my own notes, I use $\tau$ in place of $\epsilon$, but never do anything else resembling what Bourbaki do, and in particular use Hilbert's rules instead of Bourbaki's for manipulating $\tau$.

This is the eponymous operator of the [$\epsilon$ calculus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epsilon-calculus/). It was originally devised as a proof-theoretic tool for proving consistency results, and it still plays a role in proof theory (that said, for an interesting connection between the $\epsilon$-operator and computability theory, see [this paper of Towsner](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.3434.pdf) - this followed work of Kreisel and Yang).

Now as I mentioned above, the $\epsilon$-calculus treats *properties*, not *sets*, but we can reasonably conflate the two in many circumstances, and in my  opinion it's reasonable to do so in this case (although of course the original role of the $\epsilon$-operator was to deal only with  definable sets, so this is a departure from the original intent of the symbol).

Incidentally, there's [a related operator due to Frege](https://canvas.eee.uci.edu/courses/3605/files/1250341/download?verifier=fBa13CRPmnbXo7JHvNX5wXiAJvBUWWRfJ4QSG3Hm), "$\iota$," which translates as "the unique $x$ such that" - e.g. "$\iota x(x+x=1+1)$" is a term which evaluates to $1$ in the structure $(\mathbb{N}; +, \times, 0, 1)$. (Analogously to "$\epsilon$," we need a special clause in the semantics of "$\iota$" if the relevant contidion - in this case, the existence of a unique object with the given property - is not met; in this context, a *nil individual* (for "undefined") is usually introduced to handle this.)

Note that the operators "$\epsilon$" and "$\iota$" are very odd, from the perspective of contemporary classical logic. Quantifiers turn formulas into formulas, function symbols turn terms into terms, and relation symbols turn terms into formulas; but these operators turn *formulas* into *terms*. Personally I find such things very cool! That said, there is a strong connection between such operators and generalized quantifiers, and they are often studied side-by-side when looking at the logic of natural language.

Comment: The OP must have changed the post since yesterday ...

Comment: @Bram28 Haha, yes it looks like they did! This is *exactly* why I don't want "$\epsilon$" used for this operator ...

Comment: @NoanSchweber Yes, i can see that ... Again some interesting history there, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It doens't have any sense to define an element without specifying where it is. So you can pretty much choose any symbol to represent an element, but you **have** to specify where it is.

Answer (score 1):

To say that $x$ is an arbitrary element of a set $S$ in the argument that follows, write

> Let $x\in S$ ...